# can I use newer ubuntu's source list for ubuntu 11

Tags: ubuntu

I need to use Ubuntu 11.10 and I am trying to install emacs. However, it looks like the some of the software repositories for ubuntu 11.10 are no longer there. Can I use change the sources.list to use those of newer Ubuntus, say 12, 13, 14?

Answer (score 0):

You can add those repositories to /etc/apt/sources.list, however there is no guarantee that the software downloaded for .12+ from those repositories will work on your 11.10.

Once you update the sources list, run sudo apt-get update and then try getting the desired software.